# system.reflection.targetparametercountexception parameter count mismatch Parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I am trying to Update UI using different threads and use the below process to do so.But getting the above error during invoke. Kindly advice is this not allowed.

```
    delegate void SetLabelCallback(string text,string Qmgr);
    private void Set_status(string text, string Qmgr)
    {
        if (this.Status1A.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(record_count);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text,Qmgr });
        }
        else
        {
            switch (Qmgr)
            {
                case "GCSSPR1A": this.Status1A.Text = text;
                    break;
                case "GCSSPR1B": this.B1_Status.Text = text;
                    break;
                case "GCSSPR2A": this.A2_Status.Text = text;
                    break;
                case "GCSSPR2B": this.B2_Status.Text = text;
                    break;
                case "GCSSPR3A": this.A3_Status.Text = text;
                    break;
                case "GCSSPR3B": this.B3_Status.Text = text;
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the definition of `record_count`?

Comment: Are you using C# 4? If so, you could make this code a LOT simpler and less error prone.

Comment: Typo in my Code Fixed it...

Comment: Just out of interest, is there an evenlongerexceptionmessageallinlowercase? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would also do it similarly to Baldrick.

He is using lambda expression and maybe you would use something like this

```
private void Set_status(string text, string Qmgr)
{ 
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
    this.Invoke(new ReceivedEventHandler(Set_status), new Object[] {text, Qmgr});                
    }
    else 
    {
    }
}
```

But, I don't think that is the problem.

I received this problem previously when there was a mismatch between the number of parameters in the delegate handler/function call and the number of objects defined in the Invoke declaration.

```
this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text, Qmgr, something_missing });
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: "mismatch between the number of parameters in the delegate handler/function call and the number of objects defined in the Invoke declaration." + 1

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the top of your function to something like this:

```
private void Set_status(string text, string Qmgr)
{
    if (this.Status1A.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)(() => Set_status(text, Qmgr)));
    }
    else
    {
```

This way you shouldn't need the delegate declaration, etc.